# Why isn't Messages.app text sending?

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, messages

I'm trying to text a number from my MacBook Messages.app.

I have my iPhone 7 right next to me. Running macOS Big Sur. Bluetooth and and Wi-Fi are on on both devices, both connected to home and Wi-Fi, I have and Wi-Fi calling turned on but also have two bars of signal. I am signed in with the same Apple ID on both.

In Messages.app, the loading/sending bar goes to almost complete, then freezes for a while, then there is a red circle ! sign next to the message and it says "Not delivered".

Why?

How can I use my MacBook to send texts?

---

Actually looking at it, Messages on my Mac and on my iPhone don't seem synced at all.

Comment: In Settings -> Messages on the iPhone, is Text Message Forwarding enabled for your Mac?

Comment: @KevinGrabher it wasn't